# Documenting ONLY certain code, and ignoring all others?

Tags: c#, documentation, doxygen, documentation-generation

I'm currently using doxygen on a C# project, but if this feature can be found in another documentation generator that works with C#, then I am interested.

I want the documentation generator to ignore all comments and code EXCEPT those with certain comment keywords. The functionality I want is the opposite of the doxygen `\cond` and `endcond` keywords. For example, something like:

```
///
/// This comment and variable declaration is ignored by the documentation
/// generator.
///
public double MySecretPublicVar;

/// /doc-this
/// This comment and variable declaration is documented by the documentation
/// generator.
/// /doc-this-end
public double MyDocumentedVar;
```

Comment: I suppose one option would be to always place a "/cond" at the top, and a "/endcond" at the bottom, of every file. And then when I want something documented, I start that section with a "/endcond" and end it with a "/cond". But that's still pretty ugly.

Comment: You could try something with a `FILTER_PATTERN` /`INPUT_FILTER` and of course the files that you know off that don't have documentation you can leave out of the `INPUT` tag  or place in the `EXCLUDE` tag.

Answer (score 0):

[VSdocman](https://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html) tool (I'm working in the company that makes it) can do it flexibly with [regex filters](https://www.helixoft.com/files/vsdocman/help/regex_filters.html). In your case you just specify an "include" filter for signature with XML comments. If you want to match any of the "key_word1" or "key_word2" in it, use regex like:
**.*my_keyword1|my_keyword2.***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The closest match to your desired functionality is the [@internal](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdinternal) command. It still works inverse to what you want, but might be more convenient than wrapping everything in conditional blocks. You will need to take care that `@internal` is the first thing in the doc block.

In addition you will probably need to set the configuration `HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS` and `HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES` to truly remove `MySecretPublicVar` from the documentation (because if set to internal it only removes the documentation). And make sure that `EXTRACT_ALL` is set to false.

And even then you probably need to take care that things you want internal not accidentally slip through. So yeah, doxygen is not really suitable/convenient for your use case, or at least requires a bit of effort to do it.